# symfony2 doctrine oneToMany relation doesnt retrieve the right entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine, one-to-many

I have an entity Family, which has two fields, one dad, one mom, with a OneToOne relation to a Parent entity. The problem is that my Family has a Member field too, with a OneToMany bidirectional relation witch my Member entity (the children).

When i create a family and a member, no problem, it is persisted. But when i want my family back, under the Member field, I have my two Parents... And i dont understand why.

Here is the relation for Member

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Interne\FichierBundle\Entity\Family", inversedBy="members")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="family_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $family;
```

and for Family :

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Interne\FichierBundle\Entity\Membre", mappedBy="famille", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
private $membres;
```

The getters and setters are correct, I've done many generate:entities and clear:cache too
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is an issue from copying your code but there is a type:

you expect the property members on your family:

```
inversedBy="members")
```

but your property has actually the name "membres"

```
private $membres;
```

Comment: also famille should be named $family like the attribute on Member class.

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo by copying my code as i translate it from french. Anyway, the problem was my inheritance, which i didnt handle properly. Thanks anyway !